# Rails model for publishable posts

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to dry up this Rails post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders]
  validates_presence_of :title
  scope :published, -> { where('hidden = ? AND published_at IS NOT NULL AND published_at < ?', false, DateTime.now).order(published_at: :desc) }
  paginates_per 10
  attr_accessor :published_at_date, :published_at_time
  acts_as_taggable
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  after_initialize :set_default_values, :if => :new_record?

  def set_default_values
    self.ad ||= false
  end

  def published?
    if self.hidden == true || self.published_at.blank?
      false
    else
      self.published_at < DateTime.now ? true : false
    end
  end

  def not_published?
    if self.hidden == true || self.published_at.blank?
      true
    else
      self.published_at < DateTime.now ? false : true
    end
  end

  def can_publish?
    !published_at.blank? && hidden?
  end
end
```

The first thing I am removing is the default value section as that can be changed to a database default to set the initial value of the `ad` attribute to false each time.

```
after_initialize :set_default_values, :if => :new_record?

def set_default_values
  self.ad ||= false
end
```

The next part I am struggling with is the `published?` and `not_published?` methods. They should return a boolean value. In trying to try up the `published?` by removing `self` and the `hidden = true` for `hidden?`. In the `else` part of the conditional, I remove the `? true : false` as the evaluation of the `published_at < DateTime.now` will return boolean from the method.

```
def published?
  if hidden? || published_at.blank?
    false
  else
   published_at < DateTime.now
  end
end
```

The `not_published?` method follows the same, but flipping the greater than sign to `>`:

```
 def not_published?
  if hidden? || published_at.blank?
    true
  else
    published_at > DateTime.now
  end
end
```

Then I realized that I could just call `published?` with a not `!`... duh.

```
def not_published?
  !published?
end
```

It is starting to look pretty good but I'd like to reduce it further. How can I reduce the `published?` method such that it does not need to the `false` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do:

```
def published?
  !hidden? && published_at.present? && published_at < DateTime.now
end
```

However I would probably define something like:

```
def visible?
  !hidden?
end
```

or possible even

```
def visible?
  !hidden? && published_at.present?
end
```

And then

```
def published?
  visible? && published_at < DateTime.now
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the `visible?` as a better option of `!hidden`. I'll add that as well.